# How to suppress comments in linux ssh here script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, heredoc

When using here script in a linux bash to run commands on a remote server all the lines are printed. How can the comments be suppressed?

The output of the below code should be:

```
ls
... (whatever is in this folder)

echo -e this is a test\ndone
this is a testndone

exit
```

Is this possible? 
The reason for doing this is that the commands and comments are more complex making the output hard to read. That should be prettier.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -tt hogan@123.123.123.123 <<EOF
  # this line get printed
  ls

  # and this comment also
  echo -e this is a test\ndone

  # exit ssh
  exit
EOF

#end of script
```

Comment: why not pass in a cmd line argument, which if set, echo's your debug info. you then surround your debug comments with an if statement, checking if some flag was set... say "--debug" or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `sed` to filter out comments and blank lines. The following will also strip comments that follow a command on the same line:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/[[:blank:]]*#.*//; /^$/d' <<EOF | ssh -tt hogan@123.123.123.123
  # this line get printed
  ls

  # and this comment also
  echo -e "this is a test\ndone"

  # exit ssh
  exit
EOF
```

Comment: This comes near, however it seems to filter out the commands as well so that just the output show up. Does it not on your side?

Comment: You're right! I had the ssh and the sed backwards. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the command try typing

```
| grep -v "^[[:space:]]*#"
```

so for example,

```
cat temp.txt | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*#"
```

Comment: When I use cat, it won't execute the commands. It should but the comments should not be sent / executed.

Comment: cat is just a command to read text from a file and output that to stdout. That was just for an example. You'd actually run something like ./my_script.sh | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*#"

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be asking for this

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' <<EOF | ssh -tt hogan@123.123.123.123  
  # this line get printed
  ls

  # and this comment also
  echo -e this is a test\ndone

  # exit ssh
  exit
EOF
```